# Selenium - Python - Select dropdown meun option - No ID or Name

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu

I am trying to select and element in a dropdown menu:

The HTML is:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
       <select data-bind="options: indicator_type_list,value: indicatorType,optionsCaption: 'Choose...', disable: $root.mode().isReadOnly()">
        <option value="">Choose...</option>
        <option value="Malicious E-mail">Malicious E-mail</option>
        <option value="IP Watchlist">IP Watchlist</option>
        <option value="File Hash Watchlist">File Hash Watchlist</option>
        <option value="Domain Watchlist">Domain Watchlist</option>
        <option value="URL Watchlist">URL Watchlist</option>
        <option value="Malware Artifacts">Malware Artifacts</option>
        <option value="C2">C2</option>
        <option value="Anonymization">Anonymization</option>
        <option value="Exfiltration">Exfiltration</option>
        <option value="Host Characteristics">Host Characteristics</option>
        <option value="Compromised PKI Certificate">Compromised PKI Certificate</option>
        <option value="Login Name">Login Name</option>
        <option value="IMEI Watchlist">IMEI Watchlist</option>
        <option value="IMSI Watchlist">IMSI Watchlist</option>
       </select>
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
Select = Select(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(.,'Choose...Malicious E-mailIP WatchlistFile Hash WatchlistDomain WatchlistURL WatchlistMalware ArtifactsC2AnonymizationExfiltrationHost CharacteristicsCompromised PKI CertificateLogin NameIMEI WatchlistIMSI Watchlist')]"))
```

and

```
test = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='Malicious E-mail']") 
dropdown = test.find_element_by_xpath('..')
select = Select(browser.dropdown)
```

However I cannot seem to find the element to select the items in the dropdown.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to locate this `select` element.

Here is one way - locate the `select` element that has a specific `option` inside:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

option_value = "Malicious E-mail"

select_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[option[@value = '%s']]" % option_value)
select = Select(select_element)
select.select_by_value(option_value)
```

Comment: Hi @alecxe! I have used you code above in order to solve the same problem but it doesn't work. Here is the link to my code. Can you hel me on that? Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49362476/python-selenium-impossible-to-select-drop-down

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Select` by giving it web element with `select` tag

```
select = Select(browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".col-lg-6 > select")) #finds the select tag
select.select_by_value("Malicious E-mail")
#or
select.select_by_visible_text("Malicious E-mail")
```

Comment: @alecxe its a fine locator, but `Select` needs select tag.

Comment: I'm not arguing with that. Just pointing out that `col-lg-6` is a "layout" oriented class coming from bootstrap. Relying on layout-oriented classes or other attributes is not recommended in general. Thanks.

Comment: Initially guy's response was sufficient until I had to deal with another dropdown with the same Div id. I tried alecxe's answer and it works in both scenarios. I learnt something from both answers so thanks for your help.